# How to upload file within input tag in TestCafé

Tags: html, css, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

Is it any possibility to upload file within `<input>` tag on the web page using TestCafe?

Here has following HTML structure:

```html
<div class="MuiButtonBaseroot-0-4-1362 MuiListItemroot-0-4-1365 MuiListItemdefault-0-4-1368 MuiListItemgutters-0-4-1373 MuiListItembutton-0-4-1374" tabindex="0" role="button" data-test="upload-file" data-uic="list-item">
  <div class="MuiListItemIconroot-0-4-1495" data-uic="list-item-icon"><svg width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 14 14" fill="currentColor"><path d="M6"></path></svg></div>
  <div class="MuiListItemTextroot-0-4-1489" data-uic="list-item-text"><span class="MuiTypographyroot-0-4-1413 MuiTypographybody1-0-4-1422 MuiListItemTextprimary-0-4-1492"><span>Upload files</span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please review [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and what types of questions [**can be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what types [**should be avoided.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: @Paulie_D Thanks for your attention! The problem is - We don't have `<input>` tag in our HTML, the button which responsible for uploading is `<button>` tag type that's why `setFilesToUpload ` function not working and TestCafe send validation error - "Element should have an <input>  tag". Above, I set HTML implementation of button which responsible for uploading files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the `<input>` element with the `type="file"` [attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file) to upload files in your tests, you can use the `setFilesToUpload` action. For additional information, please check [this topic](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/actions/upload.html) in the TestCafe documentation.
If your scenario is different, describe it in greater detail.

Comment: We don't have `<input>` tag in our HTML, the button which responsible for uploading is `<button>` tag type that's why `setFilesToUpload ` function not working and TestCafe send validation errror - "Elemenent should have an <input>  tag"

Comment: I suppose that despite the fact that your button initiates file uploading, the actual uploading works using the input type file. Are you using some components for file uploading? Anyway, it's very difficult to say something without a working example, so I would appreciate it if you prepare a sample which demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! We  resolve this issue by adding <input type="file"> component into our HTML.

Comment: You can see a detailed [description](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/recipes/basics/test-file-upload.html) of how to test file upload in TestCafe and inspect a runnable example [here](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-examples/tree/master/examples/upload-files).